# Subtract values of file from 1 awk

Tags: awk

I have a file in which there are number less than 1 from column 3 onward. I want to subtract these number from 1. File looks like this.

```
q       q       0.6     0.3     0.6
q       a       0.4     0.2     0.5
a       q       0.3     0.2     0.3
2       z       0.99    0.3     0.8
```

For this purpose I am using awk command.

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{if(NR<=1){for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){$(i)=1-$(i);}}print;}' file1
```

But it giving me unexpected result.

```
q       q       0.4     0.7     0.4
q       a       0.4     0.2     0.5
a       q       0.3     0.2     0.3
2       z       0.99    0.3     0.8
```

My expected output is this.

```
q       q       0.4     0.7     0.4
q       a       0.6     0.8     0.5
a       q       0.7     0.8     0.7
2       z       0.11    0.7     0.2
```

Comment: Do you have a header line in your original data?  Do you like to skip first line?  That would be `NR>1` and not `NR<=1`  = Line record are less or equal to `1`  (only first line match that statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement:

```
if(NR<=1)
```

means do this *only* if the record number is one or less. In other words, do it only for the first line (since no lines have a non-positive record number).

I'm pretty certain that's not what you want :-)

Use this instead:

```
{ for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) { $i = 1 - $i } ; print }
```

The following transcript (formatted nicely) shows it in action:

```
pax> echo 'q   q   0.6    0.3   0.6
+++>       q   a   0.4    0.2   0.5
+++>       a   q   0.3    0.2   0.3
+++>       2   z   0.99   0.3   0.8' | awk '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){$i=1-$i};print}'

q   q   0.4    0.7   0.4
q   a   0.6    0.8   0.5
a   q   0.7    0.8   0.7
2   z   0.01   0.7   0.2
```

Comment: Your output is showing `tab` outout, but you remove it in your `awk`, so you post some other result compare to what you actual get.

Comment: @Jotne, I refer the honorable gentleman to the phrase "formatted nicely" :-) I formatted it nicely so the answer would be easier to read. The actual output is a lot uglier.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the Line record test:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++)$i=1-$i}1' file
q       q       0.4     0.7     0.4
q       a       0.6     0.8     0.5
a       q       0.7     0.8     0.7
2       z       0.01    0.7     0.2
```